# HTTP access log is not logging custmized pattern in wso2 servers

Tags: logging, tomcat7, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb 4.8.1,
I wish to log the HTTP access details of every request for that i made a changes in **HOME\repository\conf\tomcat\catlina-server.xml** like below.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="http_access_management_console_" suffix=".log"
       pattern="%h %l %T %u %t%r %s %b" />
```

I have changed pattern as per above to get the response time of every request but I am unable to get that in **http_access_2014-10-20.log** file where as its storing in this file **http_access_management_console_.log** when i am logging in to the console through UI but as per this blog and wso2 documentation it should be stored in **http_access log** file also I am pasting to files data.

## **http_access_management_console_.log**

```
  127.0.0.1 - 6.769  [13/Oct/2014:16:15:20 +0530] "GET /carbon/log-admin/appenders-ajaxprocessor.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 1152 "https://localhost:9443/carbon/log-admin/log-admin.jsp?region=region1&item=logging_menu&loginStatus=true" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - 0.720 [13/Oct/2014:16:15:20 +0530] "GET /carbon/log-admin/js/loggingadmin.js?_=1413197120099 HTTP/1.1" 200 1199 "https://localhost:9443/carbon/log-admin/log-admin.jsp?region=region1&item=logging_menu&loginStatus=true" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - 0.086 [13/Oct/2014:16:15:22 +0530] "GET /carbon/log-admin/loggers-ajaxprocessor.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 50412 "https://localhost:9443/carbon/log-admin/log-admin.jsp?region=region1&item=logging_menu&loginStatus=true" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - 0.001 - [17/Oct/2014:15:24:22 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/js/jquery.validate.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - 0.002 - [17/Oct/2014:15:24:22 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/js/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - 0.004 - [17/Oct/2014:15:24:22 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/js/WSRequest.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - 0.001 - [17/Oct/2014:15:24:22 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/js/customControls.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - 0.001 - [17/Oct/2014:15:24:22 +0530] "GET /carbon/dialog/js/dialog.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - 0.008 - [17/Oct/2014:15:24:22 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/images/up-arrow.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

## **http_access_2014-10-20.log**

```
127.0.0.1 - %T - [14/Oct/2014:09:58:28 +0530] "POST /middleware/services/Test2Service HTTP/1.1" 200 787
127.0.0.1 -%T  - [14/Oct/2014:09:58:30 +0530] "POST /middleware/services/audit2Service HTTP/1.1" 200 381
127.0.0.1 -%T - [14/Oct/2014:10:04:31 +0530] "POST /middleware/services/TestService HTTP/1.1" 200 787
127.0.0.1 -%T - [14/Oct/2014:10:04:32 +0530] "POST /middleware/services/audit3Service HTTP/1.1" 200 381
```

Why its not getting stored in http_acess_log file.
I followed this blog[enter link description here](http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.in/2013/07/configure-access-logging-in-wso2.html)

Answer (score 1):

The WSO2 Carbon management console is exposed via Servlet (Tomcat) transports, hence the access logging format can be configured via `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`. But the ESB Passthru/NIO transports are synapse transports, and access logging for that needs to be configured separately.

It seems that the access log is not configurable via a configuration file. You will have to modify the synapse source [Access.java](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/synapse/2.1.2-wso2v4/modules/transports/core/nhttp/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/http/access/Access.java) `pattern` variable.

Comment: So the only option to modify the access log pattern is compile your own version of the synapse-nhttp-transport jar-file? For reference, this is a bug report for the issue: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2598. No activity so far...

Comment: That's the case for now.